# How would I fit this piece of text and button with the layout of the webpage?

Tags: php, html, css, layout

I have the index.php for the website I am making at the moment, and I have my website's layout.
Above the navigation bar I have a Logout button and some text which shows what account is logged in, and I need to fit the text and button to get a fixed space on the page without shifting around whenever the username is too big or too short.

http://jsfiddle.net/mxh2s/ for my JSFiddle of my index file, and here's the bit I need fixed and adjusted:

```
    <div class="autenticado">
    Está autenticado como:
    <?php
      $query = "Select * from user where id_user='".$_SESSION["user"]."'";
      $resultado = mysqli_query($ligabd, $query);
      $registos=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

      echo $registos["username"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      echo "<a href='logout.php' class='button'>Logout</a>";
    ?>
```

And sorry for having my code in Portuguese... If you have problems figuring out the code just say it and I'll try to help.

Comment: PHP code does not work in jsfiddle.

Comment: Would it be possible to see the CSS for "autenticado"?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it in your fiddle. However, would it be possible to get a demo URL. Like Ben Lee said, this doesn't render right in js fiddle.

Comment: Sure no problem, however I'm new to StackOverflow and stuff like JSFiddle, how do I get a place where I can make it all work correctly? Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Is your site local right now? Or do you have a URL that we could view? It would be much easier to inspect the element on the site if possible.

Answer (score 0):

A layout similar to this should work. However I am sort of guessing as your code example isn't very clear.

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="login">
        <button>Sign Out</button>
        <span class="username"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

A basic CSS example, obviously other attributes would vary depending on your layout.

```
#header {
width:100%;
}

#login {
width:auto;
float:right;
}

#login .username {
float:right;
width:auto;
}

#login button {
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure I know what you mean but it sounds like css positioning to me:

You could maybe position absolute the div to the top right?

.autenticado{

position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}

If you have all this code inside a fixed width container just give it position: relative; to keep it div within that.

Hope this helps, though I may have misunderstood what you want :)